# Что я могу использовать в telebot на замену <br>

Tags: python, html, telegram, telebot

Что я могу использовать в telebote вместо `<br>` (поскольку он не поддерживается). Мне надо сделать список и писать каждую строчку в отдельном сообщении не очень красиво. Я знаю, что это возможно, но не знаю как.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не поддерживается? Вот я в [документации](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_message) вполне вижу `parse_mode`

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае может подойти символ переноса строки `\n`, в python он работает следующим образом:

```py
string = "Привет\nМир!"
print(string)
```

Вывод:

```
Привет
Мир!
```

Подробнее о том, как работает этот символ вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://pythonru.com/primery/kak-perevesti-tekst-na-novuju-stroku-v-python#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20Python%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%5Cn%20.)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как полезный, либо отметить как решение